# Angular 4/5/6 multiple ngApps

Tags: angular

At my organization, we are thinking about moving to Angular 6 from Struts/Servlets, doing a complete re-write; regarding these I had few concerns, since none of us have much experience with Angular tech.

I was thinking of making a common Angular micro-service which would contain all the static resources of the application (menu, logo etc). All the menus and sub menus will be implemented as separate micro-service.

The question I was having is, How can I link all this modules together? Do you guys have any idea on this? When a menu is clicked, it will call the micro-service for that menu and it will be rendered on the screen. This means the static content remains as is and only the content portion is replaced with the menu content.

How can this be implemented...I just need an explanation how this can be achieved.

Comment: try following angular's tutorials, or other tutorials that you can find online

Comment: I would look at nrwl's nx for this. https://nrwl.io/nx/overview

Comment: @drinck that looks overkill for almost anything, creating a project from scratch (or atleast angular's default template) is easier 95% of the time, especially if the project isnt too advanced like the OP's question seems to be about

Comment: Do you mean you want separate apps? Because the scenario you described sounds just like a regular angular app with routing. One component for the static part, you place the router-outlet wherever you want the changing part. The actual content are also components.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you want to use multiple angular apps for that. Angular is a single page application framework, so multiple apps do not work very well. However, you could write a library that contains all of your shared components. Components for headers, buttons, dropdown, menus, etc... You could do this in some kinda microarchitecture style. So a library for each component. These libraries could be hosted on an internal nexus repo (or make it open source! sharing is caring!)

Comment: Making it open source woul violate the PCI compliance of my application. About making a library, can you please elaborate on this or share me a good tut? And won't this libraries have their own appComponent or something that should exist only once in the whole application? Lastly, Still is it possible to have multiple ngApps[Just for my knowledge]?

Comment: Just Google how to. There are a lot of tutorials on that. Even on the ClI wiki I believe. You can use that library just like any library. Eg  angular material2. Multiple angular apps on the same page will make your life miserable. Just don't. But you can always try. Especially routing will be a pain in the *ss.